# Import or Index Hive/HDFS data with Apache Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucene

I want to use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to import or index Hive tables stored in Parquet files on HDFS. As far as I know, the first step is to import or index data into `solr`, but I know little about that.

These are my questions:

1. Select which ways: [Data Import Handler (DIH)](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler), HTTP?
2. Solr 4.9 support index HDFS, which is different?

Environment: `solr 4.10 + CDH5.11`

Please help.

Comment: SolrCloud just stores the Solr data on HDFS... Not sure how accessible that is to Hive... But your data would be copied in two places, so you're not really "indexing a Hive table"... If you want fast SQL queries, you should be using Kudu or Impala

Comment: thanks your reply. hive path is also a HDFS. could you give me a simple example that how to load hdfs data into sorl?

Comment: Seen this? https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/searching-data-solr/

Comment: Here's the Cloudera version of that tutorial https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/search_mapreduceindexertool.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with below:-

1.) created a base table in hive

hive> create table solrinput3(username string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';

2.) loaded sample data into the table 'solrinput3' as follows :

hive> insert into solrinput3 values('sanvi');

3.) ADD JAR /opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/hive/solr-hive-serde-2.2.5.jar;

4.) Now, I have created a solr-hive integrated table as follows :

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbname.solrtest (title STRING)

STORED BY 'com.lucidworks.hadoop.hive.LWStorageHandler'

LOCATION '/lob/test/hive_test'

TBLPROPERTIES('solr.server.url' = 'http://XXXX.XXX.XXX:8983/solr',

'solr.collection' = 'myproj_collection1',

'solr.query' = '*:*');

5.) insert overwrite table solrtest select * from solrinput3;